SRTP type unification issue
this is based on an old post
SRTP Typeclasses in F#
which uses the following example
module Monad =
  let inline bind (m:^Monad) (f:'a -> '``Monad<'b>``) (x:'``Monad<'a>``) : '``Monad<'b>`` = 
    (^Monad : (member Bind : _*_ -> _) (m, f, x))

  let inline rtn (m:^Monad) (source:'a) : '``Monad<'a>`` = 
    (^Monad : (member Return : _ -> _) (m, source))

  let inline applyFromMonad monadInstance (f:'``Monad<'a -> 'b>``) (x:'``Monad<'a>``) : '``Monad<'b>`` = 
      f |> bind monadInstance (fun f' ->
        x |> bind monadInstance (fun a' ->
            rtn monadInstance (f' a')))

  let inline applyFromMonad2 monadInstance monadInstance2 (f:'``Monad<'a -> 'b>``) (x:'``Monad<'a>``) : '``Monad<'b>`` = 
      f |> bind monadInstance2 (fun f' ->
        x |> bind monadInstance (fun a' ->
            rtn monadInstance (f' a')))

where applyFromMonad reports an error (which I don't completely understand why)
Error   FS0001  Type mismatch. Expecting a ''a'    
but given a ''a -> 'b'    
The types ''a' and ''a -> 'b' cannot be unified.

my 'fix' is in applyForMonad2, this doesnt report the same error, but I cant understand why the fix works.
It feels as if the compiler decides what the constraints on the type of monadInstance are, but goes too far, i.e. it thinks that Monad instance's type must have a bind method that takes an 'a -> 'b and then later on finds out it must take a 'a, tries to unify that (rather than assuming that it could be a polymorphic type), and then fails.
Where in the second example it doesnt have to apply the same constraints to the same type because there are two of them.
Is that correct? (ish)
(this isnt production code, just an example that confuses me).
(I'm aware FS+ does something different, I'm just trying to understand why the obvious route doesnt work)

Yes, your analysis is correct in broad strokes. The ^Monad type can't have two Bind methods of different types.
But it's not just because the compiler goes "too far". Overloaded methods are not allowed in SRTP at all. Try this:
let inline f (x: 'a 
    when 'a : (member g : int -> int) 
    and 'a : (member g : string -> int))

You'll get a similar error saying that "type int does not match type string".

ok, but there IS a valid function bind, its valid in both cases, its just polymorphic of ('a -> m 'b) -> m 'a -> m 'b , is that SRTPs dont handle this?

m 'a is not a thing in F#. No support for higher-kinded types.

I think this is related to a fundamental limitation of Hindley-Milner type inference: Only let-bound constructs can be polymorphic and instantiated differently. Since monadInstance is an argument to applyFromMonad, it's not let-bound, and thus its bind can't be instantiated twice with different types in the body of the function.
Here's a simple example that illustrates the same sort of problem without SRTP and member functions:
let id x = x
let good = id 5, id "hello"   // id is let-bound, so the result is (5, "hello")
let bad =                     // id is not let-bound, so this won't compile
    (fun id ->
        id 5, id "hello") (fun x -> x)


oooo, i'll have to think about this.
